# Discrete Math - reflexive and symmetric demonstration

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Just introduced to discrete math and I am stuck with following demonstrations.

> Let $ R $ be a relation on $ E $. Demonstrate that:
>
> - $ R $ is reflexive if and only if $ \operatorname {Id} _ E \subseteq R $;
> - $ R $ is symmetric only and only if $ R = R ^ { - 1 } $.

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried?

Comment: For the first one, I think you mean $\operatorname{Id}_E\subseteq R$

Comment: Weel i just got introduced to the subject and really   tried  this,
<img  src="https://i.ibb.co/kQpZ4Xp/mimi-1.jpg" ></img>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this kind of proof is mostly remembering the definitions. suppose R is a relation over A.
for the first point, use the definition:
$$\text{R is reflexive} \iff \forall x\in A.<x,x>\in R$$

and we have:
$$R \text{ is reflexive} \iff \forall x\in A.<x,x>\in R \iff \{<x,x>|x \in A \} \subseteq R \iff Id_A \subseteq R $$
$\blacksquare$

for the second one, we use the definition:
$$ \text{R is symmetric} \iff \forall <x,y>\in R. <y,x>\in R$$
and so we get:
$$\text{R is symmetric} \iff \forall <x,y>\in R. <y,x>\in R  \iff \{<y,x>|<x,y>\in R\} \subseteq R \\ \iff R^{-1} \subseteq R$$
$\blacksquare$
hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does,  A great thank to you.  Have to dive into my Course one more time.